# String Object creation without using new keyword

Tags: java, string

I was studying Strings in Java can anyone tell me if we write

```
String s = "deepak";
```

will this create an object in string constant pool or not because we are not using `new` keyword here so according to me object will not be created?

Answer (score 2):

`String s = "deepak";` will try to reuse a String. If it already exists in the String pool then that object will be used. If it doesn't exists, obviously a new object will be created.

`String s = new String("deepak");` will always create a new String which won't be added to the String pool.

A simple test to confirm it (reminder: `==` compares object references):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String a = new String("test");
    String b = new String("test");
    String c = "test";
    String d = "test";

    System.out.println(a == b);
    System.out.println(b == c);
    System.out.println(c == d);
}
```

Output:

```
false
false
true
```

In case if you want to read more about this mechanism, it is called String Interning.